# How to add parameters configuration of new operator with rapidminer?

Tags: java, rapidminer

After creating a new operator and testing it, I need to set some configuration such as the definition of minsupp for frequent itemsets algorithms. Actually, I am defining this parameter inside my java code. **I like the minsup parameter be viewed in the parameter list when I select the new operator in the Rapidminer GUI**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add instances of PArameterType to a list and returning that list. following is an example:

```
@Override
public List<ParameterType> getParameterTypes() {
    List<ParameterType> types = super.getParameterTypes();
    types.add(new ParameterTypeDouble(MinSupp, "Defines the the minimum frequence of an Itemset", 0.0, 1.0));
    types.addAll(RandomGenerator.getRandomGeneratorParameters(this));
    return types;
}
```

and Thanks Marius,

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to add parameters to the operator, which are displayed in the GUI.

For that, you have to implement the function getParameterTypes() of your operator. You can get examples about the usage in almost every other operator. An operator with a lot of different parameters that can serve as a good reference is e.g. the k-Means operator, implemented in the class KMeans.
The basic concept is to add instances of ParameterType to a list and returning that list. The RapidMiner framework will do the rest.